# Port forwarding in host only network with iptables

Tags: iptables, virtualbox, virtual-machine, port-forwarding, forwarding

I have two machines in a host-only network. One is a client and the other one is a webserver.

I want to forward all HTTP traffic from client to web server over a proxy on port 8080.

I tried it with:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -I eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

but that doesn't work.

Does anybody have an idea how I can do it?

I use mitmproxy, and if I do it like that, it works:

```
curl http://10.0.2.2/example --proxy localhost:8080
```

But it doesn't work with my iptables configuration and without the `--proxy` option.